# I'm getting a memory leak for fopen_s but nothing is 'new'ed or 'malloc'ed

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I'm using MS VS2010 with a plugin called Deleaker to spot any memory leaks I might miss. It's telling me that there is 2 memory leaks on the fopen_s line but I'm not using new or malloc on anything on that line.
Every other time it has found a leak, the location has been spot on so I don't think it's looking at the wrong line. any suggestions?

**Notes**: *Image loads fine, I'm using LibPNG, OPAL is my own DLL, image and image->data are freed in the application using this DLL.*

I hope I've given enough info (*And not too much*)

```
OPAL_API void LoadPNGImage(const char* filename, OPAL::GUI::ImageStruct *&image)
    {
        int bit_depth, color_type, interlace_type;
        png_structp png_ptr;
        png_infop info_ptr;
        png_uint_32 width, height;
        unsigned char* line;
        unsigned int sig_read = 0;
        unsigned int x, y;
        FILE *fp;
        image = (OPAL::GUI::ImageStruct*)malloc(sizeof(OPAL::GUI::ImageStruct));
        memset(image, 0, sizeof(OPAL::GUI::ImageStruct));
        if(fopen_s(&fp, filename, "rb")) // 2 MEMORY LEAKS DETECTED HERE (False Positive??)
        {
            image = NULL;
            return;
        }
        png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (png_ptr == NULL)
        {
            free(image);
            image = NULL;
            fclose(fp);
            return;
        }
        png_set_error_fn(png_ptr, (png_voidp) NULL, (png_error_ptr) NULL, user_warning_fn);
        info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
        if (info_ptr == NULL)
        {
            free(image);
            image = NULL;
            fclose(fp);
            png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, png_infopp_NULL, png_infopp_NULL);
            return;
        }
        png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
        png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, sig_read);
        png_read_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);
        png_get_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, &width, &height, &bit_depth, &color_type, &interlace_type, int_p_NULL, int_p_NULL);
        png_set_packing(png_ptr);
        image->width = width;
        image->height = height;
        image->data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 4 * image->width * image->height);
        memset(image->data, 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * 4 * image->width * image->height);
        if(!image->data)
        {
            free(image->data);
            free(image);
            image = NULL;
            fclose(fp);
            png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, png_infopp_NULL, png_infopp_NULL);
            return;
        }
        line = (unsigned char*)malloc(width * 4);
        if(!line)
        {
            image = NULL;
            fclose(fp);
            png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, png_infopp_NULL, png_infopp_NULL);
            return;
        }
        for(y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            png_read_row(png_ptr, (unsigned char*)line, png_bytep_NULL);
            for(x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                switch(color_type)
                {
                    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY:
                        // Don't wanna support this mode until I need it
                        break;
                    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE:
                        // Don't wanna support this mode until I need it
                        break;
                    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB:
                        image->data[4 * ((y * width) + x) + 0]  = (unsigned char)line[(3 * x) + 0];
                        image->data[4 * ((y * width) + x) + 1]  = (unsigned char)line[(3 * x) + 1];
                        image->data[4 * ((y * width) + x) + 2]  = (unsigned char)line[(3 * x) + 2];
                        image->data[4 * ((y * width) + x) + 3]  = (unsigned char)255;
                        break;
                    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA:
                        image->data[(4 * ((y * width) + x)) + 0]    = (unsigned char)line[(4 * x) + 0];
                        image->data[(4 * ((y * width) + x)) + 1]    = (unsigned char)line[(4 * x) + 1];
                        image->data[(4 * ((y * width) + x)) + 2]    = (unsigned char)line[(4 * x) + 2];
                        image->data[(4 * ((y * width) + x)) + 3]    = (unsigned char)line[(4 * x) + 3];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        free(line);
        png_read_end(png_ptr, info_ptr);
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, png_infopp_NULL);
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Turns out it's the filename.
I didn't think I needed to clear that when it is passed directly as a const char*

is this the leak detector false flagging me or do I actually need to free that somehow?

**function is called like this**: `LoadPNGImage("images\\tiles00.png", tiles);`

Comment: looks OK to me. You could try assigning the return code to an errno_t variable, or initialising the fp to NULL before passing it in. I'd say its likely warning about the double-pointer of fp.

Comment: There are some bugs with the handling of `image`, although possibly not relevant to the detected memory leak. If the `fopen_s` fails, `image` is not free'd. Also, you test image->data *after* memsetting it; if it were null, the memset would segfault. And if a malloc for line fails, you don't free either image or image->data.

Comment: Did you try reducing your code to see if the leak goes away? Just open and close the file, do you still detect a leak? If you don't detect a leak, slowly reintroduce your code, that might help finding the location of the problem.

Comment: @rici Thanks, can't believe I missed those. Didn't stop the leak error, but if it happend to trip any of those checks it would have had problems :)

Comment: @Mustafa Ozturk
I reduced the code to just the fopen_s and the fclose
Same leak detected on the same line...

Comment: I also tried changing it to: `if(!(fp = fopen(/*&fp,*/ filename, "rb")))`
to not use the double pointer, still has the same leak detected.
they type of leak is "Heap Memory" if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when functions like fopen make a one time allocation. If you then call fopen again you will not get more leaks.

Deleaker tries to hide such "known leaks" but sometimes they are still shown.

Debugging this case I see that "leak" comes from this code inside CRT:

```
int __cdecl _mtinitlocknum (
    int locknum
    )
{
...
        if ( (pcs = _malloc_crt(sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION))) == NULL ) { <-- HERE!
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return FALSE;
    }
...
            _locktable[locknum].lock = pcs;
```

This allocation should be freed here in _mtdeletelocks:

```
void __cdecl _mtdeletelocks(
    void
    )
{
...
    for ( locknum = 0 ; locknum < _TOTAL_LOCKS ; locknum++ ) {
        if ( _locktable[locknum].lock != NULL &&
             _locktable[locknum].kind != lkPrealloc )
...
            _free_crt(pcs);
```

_mtterm (and it seems only _mtterm!) calls _mtdeletelocks. But _mtterm is not called at all as I can see. Probably it is not a big leak for CRT if CRT is used by an EXE.

At the same time if a DLL uses CRT, then _mtterm is called in DLL_PROCESS_DETACH handler - for a DLL such leaks seem to be important (a DLL can be loaded an unloaded several times)!

Answer (score 0):

If `fopen_s` fails to open the file, you should free the `image` array.  The tool might be reporting the leak with a line number slightly off.  The fix is simple:

```
    if (fopen_s(&fp, filename, "rb")) {
        free(image);
        image = NULL;
        return;
    }
```

More questions:

- why not use `calloc` instead of `malloc` and remove the calls to `memset`?
- why not test for memory allocation failure?
- why not free allocated objects in reverse order of construction in case of `png_create_info_struct` and similar failures?
- why not destroy `info_ptr` in case of later memory allocation failure?
- many missing deallocation calls if `line` cannot be allocated.
- no test for failure to read image data by `png_read_row`

Error handling done this way is very tedious and error prone.  You should either use C++ paradigms such as RAII, or use a common error handling point that checks the various objects agains `NULL` or `nullptr` and deallocates them in order.

Comment: All good suggestions which will improve my coding, Not the answer though :)